# FireMonkey - workaround for the missing OnSetValue event in TPopupColumn

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, tgrid

Changes in the TPopupColumn (TGrid) do not trigger the OnSetValue event so I cant get the value from it set by the user (GetValue works fine).
The problem was already reported in the QualityCentral: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx/qcmain.aspx?d=113448

Have any of you found a workaround?
Is there any other way to get the value from TPopupColumn in order to combine it with for example OnMouseDown event? I tried with numerous properties of TPopupColumn but with no effect.

I will appreciate any suggestions since I would really like to keep the TPopupColumn in my project.

I'm using Delphi XE5 with Update 1.

========================SOLUTION===========================

Based on the guide posted by Mike Sutton I end up adding the following line to the TPopupColumn.CreateCellControl function in FMX.Grid.pas file.

```
TPopupCell(Result).OnChange := DoTextChanged;
```

Than I saved a copy of the file and added it to my project which fixed the problem.

Comment: I can't believe EMBT still haven't fixed this!